# Set up Wiremock to return different http status code/response for different tests and same url

Tags: spring-boot, testing, integration-testing, wiremock

I have two tests to prove that the 200 call from a remote service is being handled correctly and another test for the 404 scenario.

This is the Wiremock set up for each test:

200

```
    mockService.stubFor(
            WireMock.get(
                            WireMock.urlPathEqualTo(
                                    version + "/appointments"
                            )
                    )
                    .withQueryParam("id", WireMock.equalTo(id))
                    .willReturn(
                            WireMock.aResponse()
                                    .withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                                    .withHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                                    .withBody(copyToString(SomeObject))
                    )
    );
```

404

```
    mockService.stubFor(
            WireMock.get(
                            WireMock.urlPathEqualTo(
                                    version + "/appointments"
                            )
                    )
                    .withQueryParam("id", WireMock.equalTo(id))
                    .willReturn(
                            WireMock.aResponse()
                                    .withStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value())
                                    .withHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    )
    );
```

If I run each test separately, they work as expected, when I run the whole test suite, the test that's supposed to handle the 404 scenario fails since the response is always 200 instead of 404.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide more context? Does the ID differ from each test or do you use the same ID?

Comment: The ID differs, yes

Comment: I think that you need to use URLPathPattern because otherwise (AFAIR) the query parameter is not taken into account due to the fact that the path matches. When running the whole test suite the NOT_FOUND stub overwrites the OK stub as both urlPathEqualTo are the same and the queryParameter is not taken into account.

Comment: try to run `WireMock.resetAllRequests();` before each test